# How can I overwrite the browsable API HTML page in Django Rest Framework for a specific URL?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I need to overwrite the browsable HTML page corresponding to a specific URL, which will be visible to the client.

Comment: Its the page one can see while calling a DRF api via a browser

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a custom renderer for that view/url.

```
class MyBrowsableAPIRenderer(BrowsableAPIRenderer):
    template = 'my-template.html'

class MyViewSet(ViewSet):
    renderer_classes = [JSONRenderer, MyBrowsableAPIRenderer]
```

That will then use the custom renderer only for your view/url.